# Math font with lualatex

Tags: luatex, unicode-math, mnsymbol

The result is never satisfying for Minion Pro and `lualatex`. I manage to get a result close to perfection with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[SmallCapsFeatures={Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol10}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{MinionPro-It}
\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}

\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}
\[\sfrac{1}{2\pi} \quad \sqrt{3}\]
\end{document}
```

In that configuration so far the sfrac fails (missing /). If I exchange the line `MnSymbol10` with `MdSymbol` then sfrac works but sqrt doesn't. I know this usage of `MnSymbol` is maybe not the right way to do it (just noticed $\bullet$ is missing also), as they aren't organized in regular with many number (5 -> 12) and I've no clue what it means.

Any idea how to get everything working?

Comment: Do you know about Typoma's [Minion Math](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
\setmathfont[range="002F]{MdSymbol-Regular}
```

as last line the the `\setmathfont` series

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to use MdSymbol instead of MnSymbol? If the sqrt problem is solved...

Comment: It is the same the other way round with setting `range` to the root symbol

Comment: In fact it's the flat part of the sqrt that is problematic, as it is replaced with a black square. But ok "221A does the job. No nice solution but just hacking...