# General guide on how to set up Minion Pro for math in lualatex

Tags: math-mode, luatex, unicode-math, mnsymbol

### [**Minion Pro**](https://typekit.com/fonts/minion-pro)

is one of the most beautiful fonts and comes with many Adobe products.
A complementary set of symbols is provided by the [**MnSymbol**](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol) fonts and package, which is not fully compatible to **lualatex**.

However the best option would be [**Minion Math**](http://www.typoma.com/en/fonts.html), which is commercial, with hardly any free alternative. But...

### I'd like to use Minion Pro also for math in lualatex - how can I do that?

[**This answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218989/math-font-with-lualatex) already gives a good starting point and
[**this one**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex) provides extensive explanations around this issue. There are various more questions about this topic, but I haven't found one giving a complete solution.

Using the linked starting point, one already gets all letters of **Minion Pro** in the math environment together with mathematical symbols provided by **MnSymbol**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle,Ligatures = TeX,SmallCapsFeatures = {Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
 \mathscr{D}^{\gamma}   f(t)= \mathscr{D}^{m} \mathscr{I}^{m-\gamma}  
 f(t)=\frac{\partial^m }{\partial t^m} \Bigg[ \frac{1}{\Gamma(m-\gamma)}  
 \int\limits_{0}^{t} \frac{f(\tau )}{(t-\tau)^{\gamma-m+1}} ~\partial{\tau}  \Bigg] \:, 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A =
\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{array} \right) \qquad
B =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\
a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} 
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
y = \sqrt{\frac{z^2}{\ln{z}}} + z \,\Bigg|_{z\,=\,z_0}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The minimal example from the other [**linked answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166185/36835) comes out quite faulty as well.

[image]

### There are a lot of things not working correctly:

1. partial differential `\partial` and the vertical line character `|` is missing
2. the integral and `\sum` symbols are too small
3. all brackets are not scaling with size of its wrapped content and size specifier like `\Bigg(` don't work neither
4. brackets of matrices don't work
5. the square root does not scale
6. `\mathscr` does not bring any difference
7. the comma symbol is missing
8. the greek letter `epsilon` is undefined in MinionPro (at least in old font versions)
9. to be continued ...

**How can I fix them?**

---

### There is an **alternative approach** avoiding `unicode-math`

and use the non-unicode implementation of `MnSymbol`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}


\setmainfont[...

\begin{document}
...
```

Which is certainly a working option, but everything looks a little mixed up and I'm not happy with the result.

[image]

If you consider this the better approach, feel free to post an answer providing a solution, which gets everything harmonizing a little better.

---

I'm aware that there are no *real solutions* unless the OpenType version of **MnSymbol** gets patched for use in `unicode-math`. This question is self-answered as I thought it would be worth sharing the (in my opinion) pleasant result, though it is just an ugly workaround.

**Please feel free to provide better and simpler workarounds or even part-solutions.**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The bottom line at the top.

**Don't try this at home kids! Using MnSymbol with unicode-math will kill your time!**

---

The symbols provided by **MnSymbol** are not set up for use with `unicode-math`. Some are missing, some are not scalable in size. These need to be replaced by a different math font. 
For my opinion **XITS Math** does a good job. One just needs to find the [**unicode characters**](http://unicode-table.com/en/) due to fix.

Partial differential `\partial`:

```
\setmathfont[range={"2202} ]{XITS Math}
```

The integrals with an additional little tweak:

```
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C}]{XITS Math}
\newcommand{\intX}[2]{\int\limits_{\mkern-15mu #1}^{#2} \mkern-15mu}
```

For the sum symbol I personally find the **Latin Modern Math** symbol a better match:

```
\setmathfont[range={"2211} ]{Latin Modern Math}
```

The  brackets come with a quite heavy weight in **XITS Math**, so also used **Latin Modern Math** in this case:

```
\setmathfont[range={"005B,"005D,"0028,"0029,"007B,"007D} ]{Latin Modern Math}
```

The vertical line character though, is too bold there, so back to **XITS Math**

```
\setmathfont[range={"007C} ]{XITS Math}
```

Fixing the root:

```
\setmathfont[range={"002F,"221A}]{XITS Math}
```

and the comma:

```
\setmathfont[range={"002C} ]{XITS Math}
```

and finally the `\mathscr` and additionally the `\mathrm` characters

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
```

The letter `\epsilon` is missing, but `\varepsilon` is working. As we use **unicode-math** the replacement with `\let` needs to be done at the begin of the document:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\phi\varphi
\let\epsilon\varepsilon
}
```

or `\AfterEndPreamble` in case there are problems with **hyperref** and the **etoolbox** package.

One further problem is the slash `/`, where it is a matter of taste, which font should be use for replacement.

```
\setmathfont[range={"002F,"2215}]{Latin Modern Math}
```

But the actual mistake of the author of the original MWE was, that he should have used `\mathbin{/}` instead of `/` for a better spacing.

**All these fixes together give a pleasant result:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Numbers = OldStyle,Ligatures = TeX,SmallCapsFeatures = {Renderer=Basic}]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Scale=MatchLowercase]{Minion Pro}
\setmonofont[Numbers=OldStyle,Scale=MatchLowercase]{Minion Pro}

\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={"005B,"005D,"0028,"0029,"007B,"007D} ]{Latin Modern Math} % brackets
\setmathfont[range={"2202} ]{XITS Math}  % partial
\setmathfont[range={"2211} ]{Latin Modern Math}  % sum
\setmathfont[range={"007C} ]{XITS Math}  % vertical
\setmathfont[range={"221A} ]{XITS Math}  % root
\setmathfont[range={"222B-"2233,"2A0B-"2A1C}]{XITS Math}  % integrals
\setmathfont[range={"002F,"2215}]{Latin Modern Math} % / 
\setmathfont[range={"002C} ]{XITS Math} % ,
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}

\newcommand{\intX}[2]{\int\limits_{\mkern-15mu #1}^{#2} \mkern-15mu}

\AtBeginDocument{\let\epsilon\varepsilon}

\begin{document}
...
```

[image]

Also the output produced by `\blindmathpaper` looks nice:

[image]

---

### The neverending story.

Probably you will still find something missing. The last issue I encountered before I gave up, was the missing full stop/punctuation mark as discussed in [**this question**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239925/full-stop-missing-in-mnsymbol-replacement-renders-brackets-with-cdots-why/239930) and also solved with [**this answer**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207554/36835). But even then commands like `\dots` still did not work. Realizing that one needs to fix almost everything of **MnSymbol**, so actually nothing is left, I decided to use another math font and just included some certain symbols of **MnSymbol** I'd liked.

I finally use this settings:

```
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}
\setmathfont[range=\mathscr,StylisticSet={1}]{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range={"005B,"005D,"0028,"0029,"007B,"007D,"2211,"002F,"2215 } ]{Latin Modern Math} % brackets, sum, /
\setmathfont[range={"002B,"002D,"003A-"003E} ]{MnSymbol} % + - < = >
\setmathrm{Minion Pro}
```

---

### The bottom line at the bottom.

**Don't try this at home kids! Using MnSymbol with unicode-math will kill your time!**

The whole thing is so buggy, that it is not worth trying. Maybe in the future. Using another font as base and include certain symbols from **MnSymbol** seems appropriate though.

Comment: MnSymbol includes all necessary symbols. Using the `MinionPro` and `MnSymbol` package with pdflatex produces very good results.

Comment: With lualatex obviously not. That what this Q&A is supposed to fix.

Comment: Well, the symbols are present in the font but the set-up is not correct. Thus, a better solution would be correct the set-up, if that's possible...

Comment: @sebschub sure, this is [**discussed extensively in one of the linked answers**](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152714/possible-to-use-mnsymbol-with-luatex). I'm aware that this is just a workaround. Feel free to post a different approach :)

Comment: @sebschub there is a bug in `MinionPro` package with `minionint` option and using `\complement` command